# How to insert a link in an e-mail with JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-mail

I want to insert a link into an e-mail with JSP. I recieve the HTML message succesfully in my e-mail but the link is not displaying... I'm using Java mail... my code is this:

```
public void sendConfirmationMail() throws MalformedURLException, IOException{
    try {
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");    
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");                        
        Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(properties,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    @Override
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(fromEmail,password);
        }
        });
        mailSession.setDebug(true);
        MimeMessage mail = new MimeMessage(mailSession);      
        mail.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail));
        mail.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(toEmail));
        MimeBodyPart cuerpo = new MimeBodyPart();
        cuerpo.setText(message,"UTF-8","html");
        Multipart part = new MimeMultipart();
        part.addBodyPart(cuerpo);
        mail.setContent(part);
        mail.setSubject(subject);
        Transport.send(mail);
    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MailController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: First, fix all these [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).  I don't see any links in your code, or any use of JSP, so it's hard to tell what you're doing that's not working.  If `message` is a String containing html content, what does the link look like in the html code?

Comment: is your linke inside `mesasge`? since your message is html have you tried putting the link inside `<a href="url">link text</a>`?